# Get results from Multiple gallery ID's in nextgen

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I think this is more an SQL related question than a WP related question :::

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( " SELECT *
from wp_ngg_gallery, wp_ngg_pictures
where wp_ngg_pictures.galleryid = wp_ngg_gallery.gid
and wp_ngg_gallery.gid = 10
order by wp_ngg_pictures.imagedate 
DESC " );
```

Above is a query that works fine if I'm only getting data from Gallery ID = 10 a single gallery id ( eg. 10 in example ) ::: I want to retrieve data from more than one Gallery ID how could I achieve this ( eg. 10,8,4 ) :::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `IN`

```
wp_ngg_gallery.gid IN (10,8,4 )
```

full query using `ANSI SQL-92` syntax

```
SELECT  *
FROM    wp_ngg_gallery
        INNER JOIN wp_ngg_pictures
            ON wp_ngg_pictures.galleryid = wp_ngg_gallery.gid
WHERE   wp_ngg_gallery.gid IN (10,8,4)
ORDER BY wp_ngg_pictures.imagedate DESC
```